# Flutter Maps Overlay Issue

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I'm working on Flutter for an app that uses Google Maps. The app is made up of 2 activities: a list and the map.

This paragraph is just some background information. You may skip it. Usually Google Maps let you call a map by tapping a static map which opens into a dynamic one. The static map is just a small widget. The app need to directly display a full screen map on a single activity.

The issue we faced has to do with Overlays. Auby Khan from medium.com provided the code needed to display a full screen map. So we created the first activity with a button that navigates you to the second activity:

```
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.map),
            tooltip: 'openMap',
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ControlParkMapNormal()),
              );
            },
          ),
```

And in the second activity, it would display the map:

```
final size = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(ui.window).size;
final GoogleMapOverlayController controller =
GoogleMapOverlayController.fromSize(
  width: size.width,
  height: size.height,
);
final mapController = controller.mapController;
final Widget mapWidget = GoogleMapOverlay(controller: controller);

class ControlParkMapNormal extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("ControlPark"),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.list),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ControlPark()),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: MapsDemo(mapWidget, controller.mapController),
      ),
      navigatorObservers: <NavigatorObserver>[controller.overlayController],
    );
  }
}

class MapsDemo extends StatelessWidget {

  MapsDemo(this.mapWidget, this.controller);

  final Widget mapWidget;
  final GoogleMapController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(child: mapWidget);
  }
}
```

When Navigating from Activity 1 > Activity 2 > Activity 1, the map would remain displayed. It would seem that the map is permanently overlayed on all subsequent activities. The transition from Activity 1 > Activity 2 > Activity 1 > Activity 2 yields this error:

> I/flutter (12701): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 1303 pos 14: 'observer.navigator == null': is not true.

Here's the block of code for the observer navigator:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (NavigatorObserver observer in widget.observers) {
      assert(observer.navigator == null);
      observer._navigator = this;
    }
```

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?